# node.js - want to send two res within the same router POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, twilio

I have my router set up below:

```
questionRouter.post('/questionsReply', (req, res) => {
 twilioResp(req, res);
 var newResponse = new Response(req.body);
 newResponse.save((err, data) => {
  if (err) return handleDBError(err, res);
  res.status(200).json(data);
 });
 console.log('From: ' + req.body.From);
 console.log('Message: ' + req.body.Body);
});
```

I am trying to save the response received into my mongodb. However, I am getting the error of **Can't set headers after they are sent**. I am pretty sure it is because of the function above twilioResp(). That code is:

```
module.exports = exports = (req, res) => {
 var resp = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
 resp.message('Thank you! Your response "' + req.body.Body + '" has been saved!');
 res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});
 res.send(resp.toString());
};
```

This module is an automatic response to a text received through the Twilio REST API. Is there a way to call both of these within the same POST request?

Answer (score 3):

> Instead of `res.send()` you should use `res.write()` to send multiple responses.

---

> `res.send()` sends entire `HTTP` response to the client includes `headers` and `content` even it `ends the response`.
>   And after that, you can't send anything.

Comment: Thanks - the server's not crashing now but the twilioResp isn't sending anything now?

Comment: EDIT: I just added res.send after res.write() and now it works? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

You should do something like this:

```
questionRouter.post('/questionsReply', (req, res) => {
    var newResponse = new Response(req.body);
    newResponse.save((err, data) => {
        if (err) return handleDBError(err, res);
        else {
            twilioResp(req, res);
        }

    });
    console.log('From: ' + req.body.From);
    console.log('Message: ' + req.body.Body);
});
```

Comment: I had tried that and it's still not quite working - getting the same error:
 `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)`

Comment: Now the response is saved to the db, however, the twilioResp() makes the server crash...